# Enumerating installed browsers on OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos

How would one enumerate the installed browsers on an OS X system from a local app. I would like to build something like choosy, but different (long story). However, I would like to enumerate all installed browsers on the system.

On windows, I can dive the installed browsers in the Default Programs registries, however, I don't believe there is a similar concept on OS X. Do I have to manually search through all the bundles & their info.plist files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `LSCopyAllHandlersForURLScheme(CFSTR("http"))` or `LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType(CFSTR("public.html"), kLSRolesViewer)`, or the [set](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSSet/setWithArray:) [intersection](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableSet/intersectSet:) of both.

Those two functions return bundle identifiers; you can use `LSFindApplicationForInfo` to find the preferred instance on disk of an application by its bundle identifier.

(Don't forget to follow [the Core Foundation memory-management rules](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html).)

Edit: In a comment on this answer, smorgan suggests `LSCopyAllHandlersForURLScheme(CFSTR("https"))` (that's http**s**) as an alternative to the first call. This is a good suggestion.

Comment: I noticed these are Carbon APIs. I thought Carbon was being deprecated?

Comment: Launch Services is part of Core Services, not Carbon. As such, it is not deprecated, and is available on 64-bit. (See the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/ )

Comment: You might want to use "https" instead of "http", as in my experience the latter has more false-positives for things that are really browsers.

Answer (score 2):

[LSCopyAllHandlersForURLScheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1443240-lscopyallhandlersforurlscheme) has been deprecated in 10.15

You can use [LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1445148-lscopyapplicationurlsforurl) instead

```
LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(URL(string: "https:")! as CFURL, .all)?.takeRetainedValue() as? [URL]
```

Also, unlike LSCopyAllHandlersForURLScheme, LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL returns the URL of the file path of Applications.

You can then use `Bundle(url: fileURL)!.bundleIdentifier` to extract the bundleID

To extract the apps name you can use

```
Bundle(url: fileURL)!.infoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"]
```

and if `CFBundleDisplayName` returns nil then `CFBundleName` can be used

Comment: looks like `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL` is deprecated now too. What now?

Answer (score 0):

Check this to list

```
NSArray* apps = (NSArray*)CFBridgingRelease(LSCopyAllHandlersForURLScheme(CFSTR("https"))) ;
NSLog(@"%@", apps);
```

This for default:

```
NSString* defaultBundleId = (__bridge NSString*)LSCopyDefaultHandlerForURLScheme(CFSTR("https"));
NSLog(@"default is %@", defaultBundleId);
```

Answer (score 0):

[LSCopyAllHandlersForURLScheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1443240-lscopyallhandlersforurlscheme) has been deprecated in 10.15

[LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1445148-lscopyapplicationurlsforurl) has been deprecated in 12.0

From 12.0 onwards, use one of the following APIs:

[NWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(toOpen: URL) -> URL?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1533391-urlforapplication)

[NWorkspace.shared.urlsForApplications(toOpen: URL) -> [URL]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3753000-urlsforapplications)

[NWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(toOpen: UTType) -> URL?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3752998-urlforapplication)

[NWorkspace.shared.urlsForApplications(toOpen: UTType) -> [URL]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3752999-urlsforapplications)

In my experience, listing the apps that handle HTTP/HTTPS schemes is not enough to list only the browsers, because some apps also handle these schemes even though they are not browsers.

To get the list of browsers only, I intersect the list of apps that handle HTTP/HTTPS and apps that can open HTML/XHTML files. Like this:

```swift
func getBrowsersAppsURLs() -> [URL] {
    guard let schemeURL = URL(string: "https:") else {
        return []
    }
    let htmlHandlerAppsURLs: [URL]
    let httpsHandlerAppsURLs: [URL]
    if #available(macOS 12.0, *) {
        htmlHandlerAppsURLs = NSWorkspace.shared.urlsForApplications(toOpen: .html)
        httpsHandlerAppsURLs = NSWorkspace.shared.urlsForApplications(toOpen: schemeURL)
    } else {
        let htmlHandlerAppsIds = LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType(kUTTypeHTML, .viewer)?.takeRetainedValue() as! [String]
        htmlHandlerAppsURLs = htmlHandlerAppsIds.compactMap(NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier:))
        httpsHandlerAppsURLs = LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(schemeURL as CFURL, .viewer)?.takeRetainedValue() as! [URL]
    }
    return Array(Set(htmlHandlerAppsURLs).intersection(httpsHandlerAppsURLs))
}
```